# Why is Google API key restriction not working

Tags: api-key, google-geocoding-api

I have a Google API key.  It works fine.  I'm seeing traffic to the Google Geocoding API using that API key:
[image]

However, I added a restriction on the API key so that this traffic to Google Geocoding API should start denying all these requests:
[image]

Doing so has had no effect.  The Google Geocoding API continues to see traffic.  Why is it not denying these requests?  Or is it and I'll always see traffic on that graph even if it's denying the requests?  The Errors graph for that same key shows no data during that time period.

Comment: If you only allow BigQuery API in this API key's API restrictions, then you shouldn't be able to make Geocoding requests at all with that API key. Can you test this by making a Geocoding request on the browser with that API key? E.g.: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Comment: If the above request fails (REQUEST_DENIED) then the restriction does work. Please share with us the results of this test.

Answer (score 0):

You have to also select "By credential" in the 2nd dropdown.  Such an annoying design!

[image]